# Which mandatory tag should I add in case of non-technical fixes?

Tags: discussion, meta, meta-tags

I sometimes get confused while tagging a question at the time of asking on MSO in scenarios where I give a suggestion for fixing non-technical things like 'Updation of faq page', 'Change of text somewhere on some SE site', or any other such that are not related to technical fix.

In such cases, I get confused between tags [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

Please let me know, what should be the appropriate tag in such cases?

Comment: I tend to just use what feels right and wait for someone to come along and edit in the best tags.  As the Cub Scouts say, "Do Your Best!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, one of the devs once posted a comment as an aside to some otherwise-unrelated answer that said that [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) should only be used for technical bugs, or issues that would require a software engineer's time to fix. That way, they could use the bug list as a rough to-do list.

I don't have a link. I'm looking, but I don't expect to find it.

To answer your question, though, by process of elimination, use [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

Answer (score 1):

I expect [support](/questions/tagged/support) would be the right choice.

> A request for assistance with one of the site's features.

Comment: No, my concerned questions were not 'a request for assistance'. They were the minor fixes in faq page, or any mis-spelling. Please check the question. How come these post suggesting fix fall under `Support` ?

Comment: Because it's not a bug, and it's not a discussion. You're requesting assistance with a feature.

Comment: One such question was updation to a out-dated faq line. I can't imagine how this is a 'request for assistance with a feature'.

Comment: @mtk Moderators can (partially) edit the FAQ, SE employees can edit every FAQ, you can't, hence require assistance with an existing feature.

Answer (score 0):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) should be used if you want to discuss about an on-topic question with other users (e.g. "Should down-voters explain why they down-voted a post?"); if you are suggesting a text change because (for example) it doesn't follow the English grammar, or there are repeated words (such as "flagged posts for for kiamlaluno"), then I would use [bug](/questions/tagged/bug); if you are suggesting to change the text to give more information, or information that is more pertinent for the user in the given context (e.g. replace "You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits." with "The suggested edit is pending review."), then I would use [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

For what I understood, [support](/questions/tagged/support) should be used when you don't understand how a feature works, or when you are asking a tag synonym, a tag merge, or burninating a tag. If you know that something should work in a way, but it doesn't, then you are reporting a bug; if you are not sure how a feature works, you should use [support](/questions/tagged/support).